# Google Sheets Time-driven Trigger. Need Better Time Accuracy

Tags: google-sheets, eventtrigger

I have a script in Google to email the PDF of a Google Sheet on a time-driven trigger. The problem is that the range accuracy in time is 60 min. Thats stupidly inaccurate. I want this script to trigger every other day (or every day if I have to) at 10:10AM. Not between 10am-11am. 10:10am.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GAS to build a time-driven trigger that is more accurate, but still may not be as accurate as you would like - the [documentation states "plus or minus 15 minutes"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#nearMinute(Integer)).